# ec2 service policy to restrict the creation of inbound ssh public access

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, aws-policies

I need to create a AWS service control policy to restrict the creation of inbound rule for ssh with public access via the security group.
I have tried with this JSON script bellow, but I messed up with that.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:AuthorizeSecurityGroupIngress",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsEgress",
                "ec2:RevokeSecurityGroupEgress",
                "ec2:UpdateSecurityGroupRuleDescriptionsIngress"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:352571213128:security-group/*",
            "Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "192.0.2.0/24",
                        "203.0.113.0/24"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Still, inbound rule for 0.0.0.0/0 can be created. 
Need: I need for ssh protocol only.

Answer (score 2):

> inbound rule for 0.0.0.0/0 can be created.

as far I know the SourceIp means IP of the calling aws client creating the resource (sg), not value in the resource

I'm not sure you could enforce values in the SG using a policy.

> restrict the creation of inbound rule for ssh with public access via the security group

I believe you can check for public ssh groups using AWS Config (then you can have a lambda to remove or update the sg)

There is already an aws config "restricted-ssh" managed rule, though it works for ipv4 only, so you may want to create your own to ensure specific values or ipv6 support

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would be doing it with automated scripts like using CloudFormation or Terraform through which you can pass already existing/created security group which would have port 22 restriction with given IP. If not, you would be creating security group first and will attach it to newly created EC2 instance then.

If you are doing it manually, then just after EC2 instance creation you would need to go security group attach with it and change the IP range manually form 0.0.0.0/0 to your specific IP Ranges.